# I am facing a problem with spring boot logback

Tags: spring-boot

Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:logback-spring.xml'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@3f102e87 - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [vtep1024]ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@3f102e87 - [vtep1024] is not a valid conversion wordERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@27abe2cd - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [vtep1024]ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@27abe2cd - [vtep1024] is not a valid conversion word    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:166)   at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:67)

---

logback-string.xml file

```
<property resource="application.properties" />

<springProperty scope="context" name="loggingFolder" source="logging.folder" defaultValue="logs" />
<springProperty scope="context" name="loggingFileName" source="logging.file.name" defaultValue="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.log" />

<springProperty scope="context" name="loggingFileSizeMax" source="logging.file.size.max" defaultValue="10MB" />
<springProperty scope="context" name="loggingFileNameArchive" source="logging.file.name.archive" defaultValue="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-%i.log.zip" />
<springProperty scope="context" name="loggingFileArchiveMaxFiles" source="logging.file.archive.maxFiles" defaultValue="10" />

<appender name="CONSOLE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->

    <encoder>
        <pattern>[${HOSTNAME}] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${loggingFolder}/${loggingFileName}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${loggingFolder}/${loggingFileNameArchive}</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>${loggingFileArchiveMaxFiles}</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>${loggingFileSizeMax}</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[${HOSTNAME}] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%thread] [%-5level] [%logger{36}] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you have your own logback-spring.xml in your project?

Comment: same code working on some other machines, but on my machine it's throwing error...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  yaa i have.

Comment: so there must be an error in that file

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, i have attached that file, please favour me.